# How to change image size in devxpress gridcontrol in c#?

Tags: image, grid, devexpress

I am programming with c# - WinForms. I select photos from `t_person_photo`.
And via datatable I load data to `DevExpress GridControl`.
Size of the images in my table is 150x150 pixel, but when I load these images to grid I want to resize them to 50x50 pixel.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `PictureEdit` as a `RepositoryItem` of your column, here is what you can try :

1- Set the `RowHeight` property of your GridView to 50.

2- Set the `SizeMode` property of your `RepositoryItemPictorEdit` to `Squeeze`. Doing this, the image is shrunk propertionally to fit the container

Good luck